# Up/Down buttons in question title

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, questions, voting, title

I would like to upvote or downvote some questions without going to this question, because of title and short part of description are sufficient for voting decision in some cases.

I suppose to replace following old form:

[image: Question title now]
with new form:

[image: Question title with up/down buttons]

Answer (score 74):

No, you cannot judge a question quality from the summary alone.

Sorry, but I feel this is a terrible idea for that reason alone.

You need the comments, the full markup and the answers to judge a question fairly, not to mention to take a moment and vote for any answers too.

Comment: I see a Reversal badge coming on here.  :p

Comment: Should the voting for the question really depend on the answers?

Comment: @gerrit: It helps to understand the full picture. If the answer turns out to be: "Here is the documentation link", then that helps cement a 'should have researched this before asking' downvote for me, sometimes. It's rare, I'll grant you. Comments are usually a better indicator as to what happens / happened with a question.

Comment: Unfortunately, looking at the comments and answers can also cause a snowball effect and a peer pressure effect. It is a temptation to vote a certain way based on the comments of someone with high reputation and/or that I have interacted with, rather than reading and considering a question myself. But this is even more serious of a problem for people who don't understand questions. People should not be voting if they do not understand something, but they still vote anyway based on what someone else says about it.

Comment: Great answer! It's perfectly true. You should not downvote a question purely on it's title. Rather, edit the question to make it better.

Answer (score 8):

We require you to, you know, actually *read* the entire question before you can vote on its quality. There's some pretty good reasons for this:

- You might read the question in its entirety, realize that there's an awesome question trying to get out, make an edit and the question is a success.
- You might read an *answer* to the question, realize there is more to it than you thought, and up-vote it instead.

Those are two pretty compelling reasons that *actually happen every day* to keep the vote buttons on the question page itself, and we're unlikely to ever change this.

As API V 2.0 expands, *some* additional write calls will probably creep in, but I have no idea if voting would ever be part of that. That's a use case to consider in that regard, even if just guarding against it.